# Django Python - adding value to TimeField

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm creating a basic model through the Django framework in Python, which demonstrates an offer on a product which will expire after 3 hours.

This is my current model:

```
class Offers(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    original_price = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    discounted_price = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    offer_started = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    offer_expires = ?????????
```

(NB: The date is not important, which is why I have used a TimeField).

Is there a simple way to automatically set the "offer_expires" field to 3 hours after the time in the "offer_started" field? Or if not linked to this field directly, the time that the entry is added?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can do it in the `save` method. But it doesn't make sense to add 3 hours to a standalone time; you need to use a DateTimeField.